# Fitnesse automatic generate fixture class

Tags: bdd, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I'm evaluating the Fitnesse as an acceptance test tool.
Is there any way to automatically generate fixture class from fitness test pages?

Answer (score 2):

No. In the fitness test pages you define the input data and the expected results but you have to write your fixture classes by your self or if you are lucky you may find something similar with what you need in the internet (for example you could find some oracle fixture and then you don't have to write that).

Comment: Is there any way as of now?