# FitNesse: automatic fixture stub generation

Tags: code-generation, fitnesse

When I write a test in FitNesse I usually write several tables in wiki format first and then write the fixture code afterwards. I do that by executing the test in the wiki server and then create the fixture classes with names I copied from the error messages out of the failed execution of the test page.

This is an annoying process and could be done by an automatic stub generator, that creates the fixture classes with appropriate class names and method names.

Is there already such a generator available?

Comment: Question duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354485/fitnesse-automatic-generate-fixture-class

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. It sounds like you are using Fit, correct?

It sounds like an interesting feature, maybe you can create one as a plugin?

Comment: Ok then. This might be a thing to do for me. I'm using slim tables and sometimes custom tables which extend slim tables. So a customizable stub generator would make sense...